# Different ViewModel instances from the same Component

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-architecture-components

I have an Activity with a `ViewPager` that displays the same data either in a mapview (page 0) or in a list (page 1). There is some filtering happening, so I thought this filtering could be applied in the activity (which contains the views) and fed to the `ViewModel`, which via `LiveData` would update both `Fragments` (mapview and list)

The theory sounds good but when I got to implement it, my component is always injecting new instances for the activity and both fragments. I found by printing the following lines:

```
05-31 13:36:16.832 16091-16091/W/DashboardActivity: Hello com.myapp.sample.ui.dashboard.DashboardViewModel@b8bb537 from com.myapp.sample.ui.dashboard.DashboardActivity@899a9f6
05-31 13:36:17.133 16091-16091/W/MyPicksMapFragment: Hello com.myapp.sample.ui.dashboard.DashboardViewModel@59e2119 from MapFragment{72070f4 #1 id=0x7f090137 android:switcher:2131296567:0}
05-31 13:36:18.139 16091-16091/W/MyPicksListFragment: Hello com.myapp.sample.ui.dashboard.DashboardViewModel@58a33fb from ListFragment{2be0446 #2 id=0x7f090137 android:switcher:2131296567:1}
```

This line proves its the same `Component`:

```
05-31 13:47:49.509 18411-18411/com.myapp.sample.dev.debug E/DashboardActivity: Saying hello from component com.myapp.sample.di.application.DaggerApplicationComponent$ControllerComponentImpl@4ccc864 within com.myapp.sample.ui.dashboard.DashboardActivity@57a81f7
05-31 13:47:50.350 18411-18411/com.myapp.sample.dev.debug E/MyPicksMapFragment: Saying hello from component com.myapp.sample.di.application.DaggerApplicationComponent$ControllerComponentImpl@4ccc864 within MyPicksMapFragment{3443332 #1 id=0x7f090137 android:switcher:2131296567:0}
05-31 13:47:51.194 18411-18411/com.myapp.sample.dev.debug E/MyPicksListFragment: Saying hello from component com.myapp.sample.di.application.DaggerApplicationComponent$ControllerComponentImpl@4ccc864 within MyPicksListFragment{e520996 #2 id=0x7f090137 android:switcher:2131296567:1}
```

This is my activity:

```
class DashboardActivity : BaseActivity<DashboardViewModel>() {


         override fun inject() {
             Timber.e("Saying hello from component $component within $this")
             component.inject(this)
         }
   }
```

Base Activity:

```
abstract class BaseActivity<E : ViewModel> : AppCompatActivity() {

 val component by lazy { (application as SoulpicksApp)
                     .applicationComponent
                     .plus(
                             ControllerModule(this)
                     )
             }


    @Inject
    protected lateinit var viewModel: E

    }

    @CallSuper
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

       inject()
  }
```

One of the fragments:

```
  class MyPicksListFragment : BaseFragment<DashboardViewModel>() {
    override fun inject() {
            var component = (activity as DashboardActivity).component
            Timber.e("Saying hello from component $component within $this")
            component.inject(this)
        }

  }
```

Base Fragment:

```
  abstract class BaseFragment<E : ViewModel> : Fragment() {

    @Inject
    protected lateinit var viewModel: E

    @CallSuper
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        inject()
    }



  }
```

Application Component:

```
@Module(includes = [ViewModelModule::class])
class ApplicationModule(val application: Application) {
(...)
}
```

ViewModelFactory:

```
class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
        private val viewModels: MutableMap<Class<out ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>>
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {


    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T = viewModels[modelClass]?.get() as T
}

@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER)
@kotlin.annotation.Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
internal annotation class ViewModelKey(val value: KClass<out ViewModel>)
```

ViewModelModule:

```
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {

 @Binds
    internal abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory
}

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(DashboardViewModel::class)
    internal abstract fun dashboardViewModel(viewModel: DashboardViewModel): ViewModel

}
```

Controller Component:

```
@Module(includes = [ViewContainerModule::class])
class ControllerModule(val activity: FragmentActivity) {

    @Provides
    @ControllerScope
    fun context(): Context = activity

    @Provides
    @ControllerScope
    fun activity() = activity

    @Provides
    @ControllerScope
    fun layoutInflater() = activity.layoutInflater

    @Provides
    @ControllerScope
    fun fragmentManager(): android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager = activity.supportFragmentManager

    @Provides
    @ControllerScope
    fun smsAuthManager(context: Context) = SmsAuthManager(context)


    @Provides
    @ControllerScope
    fun provideConnectivityManager(context: Context): ConnectivityManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

    @Provides
    @ControllerScope
    fun provideNetworkInteractor(networkInteractor: NetworkInteractorImpl): NetworkInteractor = networkInteractor

    @Provides
    @ControllerScope
    fun provideLocationManager(context: Context): RxLocationManager = RxLocationManagerImpl(context)

    @Provides
    @ControllerScope
    fun provideNavigationController(activity: FragmentActivity) = NavigationController(activity)


}
```

Comment: Where do you call `ViewModelProviders.of(__)`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce sorry I forgot the ViewModelFactory, you can see it now.

Comment: I'll second EpicPandaForce and ask you where do you call ViewModelProvider.of()? From the code you posted it seems you blindly inject the ViewModels(I assume it has an @Inject on its constructor) bypassing the ViewModelProvider.Factory and the system handling of the ViewModels. The proper way to inject the ViewModels is to inject a custom ViewModelProvider.Factory and use that with ViewModelProvider.of(activity, injectedCustomFactory).get(DashboardViewModel::class.java) for both the activity and the fragments.

Comment: I based my implementation off https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/understanding-dagger-2-multibindings-viewmodel-8418eb372848 which does not have `ViewModelProvider.of`

Comment: That post provides just some bits of the actual full implementation. I advise you to look at the architecture Github sample. Check the module providing the ViewModels and factory https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/di/ViewModelModule.kt , check the custom factory implementation https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/viewmodel/GithubViewModelFactory.kt and...

Comment: how to use it in a fragment(although you you'll want to use it in an activity) https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/ui/user/UserFragment.kt

Comment: Fair enough, it seems I misseg that part, but then I wonder how come Dagger is properly creating and injecting my instances? Them being ViewModels from Arch components, it should not be able to do it without this Factory...

Comment: You probably have an @Inject annotation on your DashboardViewModel constructor which will make the class available for injection. The factory doesn't count because you're creating the ViewModel on your own so from the system's perspective it is like it doesn't exist(so the system will not manage the ViewModel for you).

Comment: I see your point and I think you are right. Still, it should be always injecting the same instance right?

Comment: *it should be always injecting the same instance right?* - Did you scope the DashboardViewModel class with a @Singleton or a custom scope? If not you'll not be injecting the same instance.

Comment: It will as long as I reuse the component? You can see the scope I used in the code I posted

Comment: There is no scope in the code you provided. If you don't use ViewModelProvider.of(injectedFactory)... in your code that means the dependencies provided by ViewModelModule are not being used so the class gets injected by directly instantiating it. Do you have a @Singleton or a custom scope set on the DashboardViewModel class or not?

Comment: @Luksprog No i dont... I think I need to review my understanding of Dagger lol

Comment: Have look at the project I linked to above as it shows best practices for working with Dagger and ViewModels(as well as other architecture components).

Comment: Will do thanks a lot

Comment: @Luksprog should I be creating a new Module for each class & fragments? The example shows a `MainActivityModule` but creating one for each activity/Fragment sounds like too much Boilerplate

Comment: @GabrielSanmartin You could try using a single module for activities and one for the fragments(to be honest I don't use the dagger-android specific classes so I don't know if you can do this). Also, although it may seem boilerplate, you are really writing them just once at the beginning.